# Discord.py get message embed

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How can I get the embed of a message to a variable with the ID of the message in discord.py?
I get the message with `uzenet = await client.get_message(channel, id)`, but I don't know how to get it's embed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the first Embed of your message, as you said that would be a dict():
`embedFromMessage = uzenet.embeds[0]`

To transfer the dict() into an discord.Embed object:
`embed = discord.Embed.from_data(embedFromMessage)`

Comment: I know this answer is pretty old, but now you don't need the from_data or from_dict function. the message.embeds[0] is a discord.Embed object

Answer (score 2):

You can get a list of `Embed` objects with [`uzenet.embeds`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.embeds)

Comment: Thanks, but it returns dict object.

Comment: Maybe try `uzenet.attachments` instead?