# Is there a way to see if a member is being mentioned in the embed?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am using discord.py and I am trying to get the member object from the command, and when a button is pressed, it edits the message and display's user mod log data. I got it working but in a sort of odd way, it pings the person in the message, and then the event checks to see if there was a ping in (interaction) I am wondering if there is a way to look inside the embed for a mention like instead of  `interaction.message.mentions` is there something like that for embeds instead of `message`? Thanks in advance!

```
@client.command()
async def modlogs(ctx, member: discord.Member): 
        main=discord.Embed(title=" ", description=f"{ctx.author.mention} please use the buttons below to navigate {member.mention}'s modlogs.", color=0x76dba8)
        main.set_author(name=f"{member}", icon_url = member.avatar_url)
        ram_member = member

        await ctx.send(f"{member.mention}",
        embed = main,
        components=[[
            Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Warnings", custom_id= "blue"),Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Kicks", custom_id= "red"),Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Bans", custom_id= "green")
        ]],
    )


@client.event
async def on_button_click(interaction):
    print(interaction.message)
    if interaction.message.mentions:
        if (interaction.message.mentions.__len__() > 0):
            for member in interaction.message.mentions:
                if collection2.count_documents({"_id": member.id}) == 0:
                    embed1=discord.Embed(description=f"{member.mention} has no warnings!", color=0xff0000)
                    embed1.set_author(name="Error")
                else:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Get a Message

```
Msg = await Bot.get_message(channel, id)
```

## Get an Embed

Look at the first answer to [this question][1].

```
Emb = discord.Embed.from_data(Msg.embeds[0])
```

## Get the fields

Look at the answer to [this question][2].

```
for field in Emb.fields:
    print(field.name)
    print(field.value)
```

## Get the description

Look at the first answer to [this question][3].

```
Des = Emb.description
```

## Search for the mention

```
>>> Member.mention in Des
True
```

## Searching a mention

A mention begins with ```@!``` and ends with ```>```.
So you might use this fact to search a mention into a string (Embed.description returns a string-type object).
Like this:

```
Men = Des[Des.find("<@!"):Des.find(">")]
UserID = int(Men[3:])
Member = ctx.fetch_user(UserID)
```

## Links

1. [Discord.py get message embed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688392/discord-py-get-message-embed)
2. [How to align fields in discord.py embedded messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212859/how-to-align-fields-in-discord-py-embedded-messages)
3. [discord.py Check content of embed title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65548178/discord-py-check-content-of-embed-title)
4. [How do I mention a user using user's id in discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43964328/how-do-i-mention-a-user-using-users-id-in-discord-py)

## In conclusion

I guess it will work.

Comment: Well this does not really work, as I am trying to get "member" so I can not really search the description for "member"

Comment: @ECO3X10C, do you need to get a member object from a mention in an embed description, right? Let me edit my answer

Comment: Yes, I need to get it from the embed description.