# I'd like my Discord.py bot to display a random embedded message from a single channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a discord channel that is full of embedded messages. **I would like have the bot display a random embedded message from this channel in to any other channel where the command is called, similar to the functionality shown below.**

When I call this code while pointed at the embed channel it returns an error: "discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message"

I believe this is caused by the channel being totally embeds, but I am very stupid and open to being corrected. I have confirmed that the bot has full admin privileges and thus can see/write into any channel. I've also confirmed that the below code works on *non-embeds* in other channels.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

```
@client.command()
async def bestpost(ctx):
        channel = client.get_channel(channelID)
        best_posts = []

        async for message in channel.history(limit=500):
                best_posts.append(message)
        random_bestpost = random.choice(best_posts).content

        await ctx.send(random_bestpost)
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging this a bit? Try printing out `random_bestpost` and see what it is

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688392/discord-py-get-message-embed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the channel is totally embeds, then you have to look into the message's embed rather than the message content. From there you can just send the embed or access a property of the embed and send that.

For example:

```py
@client.command()
async def bestpost(ctx):
        channel = client.get_channel(channelID)
        best_posts = []

        async for message in channel.history(limit=500):
                best_posts.append(message)
        random_bestpost = random.choice(best_posts).embeds[0]

        await ctx.send(embed=random_bestpost)
```